# Codename one Live Styles in Forms that I coded Programmatically

Tags: codenameone

Can I use normally the new feature "Live Styles configuration - (present in Simulator' s Component Inspector)"  in my Forms that I created programmatically? Or Only in Forms created using Gui builder?

If it is possible, where do "Codename One" persist that information to allow use it in runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/edit-styles-simulator.html) then yes, this works well with handcoded apps (such as the kitchen sink which I demo in the video). Next to the edit button is the name of theme/resource file where the changes will be persisted.